# In C++, can an integer array have empty element in between?

Tags: c++, arrays, null

A codechef problem states about consecutive non empty segment of an integer array. I am not asking to help me out to solve that problem, I just want to know if there is any concept of having empty elements in an integer array.

Comment: Do you refer to this problem?: http://www.codechef.com/AUG14/problems/PRGIFT

Comment: Yes, This is the problem I am referring.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing as an "empty element". Since they are talking about array *segments*, an empty segment is a sub-array of length zero.

Here is an example: there are six non-empty segments in an array `{1, 2, 3}`:

```
      { 1 } start at 0, length 1
      { 2 } start at 1, length 1
      { 3 } start at 2, length 1
   { 1, 2 } start at 0, length 2
   { 2, 3 } start at 1, length 2
{ 1, 2, 3 } start at 0, length 3
```

If you allow empty segments, one could also claim that there are four empty segments - one before the beginning of the array, one after the end of the array, and two more in between the consecutive elements of the array. These empty segments have little use to formulating the problem, so the writers have disallowed them.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. An array is a continuous segment of memory representing a number of variables of the type you chose.

What you can do is have some kind of marker. For example if you know you only store positive integers, you can use -1 as a marker that that spot is considered *empty*. In reality, it's not. There is a -1 there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your confusion is rooted in the notion of emptiness in the problem formulation. You state part of the problem definition "consecutive non empty segment" and then later refer to "having empty elements in[...]".

I believe that the problem formulation refers to the chosen segment being non empty (i.e. having a length greater than zero) and not about the properties of the entries.